# How do i set the values of a List key through gconftool-2?

Tags: gconf

I want to change the values of a gconf list key through the terminal, i'm not sure how to do it though.

`gconftool-2 --type list the/key/to/modify` but then i don't know how to put the values since it's not just one.

So, how do i set different values to a gconf list key?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should build your command line like this:

```
gconftool-2 --type list --list-type string --set /the/key/to/modify '[value1,value2,value3]'
```

As you see, you need to specify also the type of list elements, with `--list-type`.

Comment: Thanks, but i have a problem, i've typed the command with the values i wanted to set, however nothing seems to have changed, i'm trying to set values for AWN so when i add a new dock it already has the applets i want and/or need, but whenever i create a new dock the default AWN are used, why is that happening?.

Comment: The values are reported and visible in `gconf-editor`? If so, the problem moves to AWN, and I don't know it.

Comment: Yeah, gconf has the correct values but AWN ignores them?.

Comment: @Uri Herrera: don't know nothing about AWN, sorry